# WordPress Comments not showing up, am I using the right code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add comments to my custom post types, and I don't want to use the:

```
<?php wp_list_comments();?>
```

As I want to display the comment form to the left, and the comments to the right.

I've added this code:

```
           <div class="comments">
                <?php if (have_comments()) : ?>
                    <h2><?php printf(_nx('One response to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s responses to &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'comments title', 'sage'), number_format_i18n(get_comments_number()), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>'); ?></h2>

                    <ol class="comment-list">
                      <?php wp_list_comments(['style' => 'ol', 'short_ping' => true]); ?>
                    </ol>

                    <?php if (get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option('page_comments')) : ?>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pager">
                                <?php if (get_previous_comments_link()) : ?>
                                    <li class="previous"><?php previous_comments_link(__('&larr; Older comments', 'sage')); ?></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (get_next_comments_link()) : ?>
                                    <li class="next"><?php next_comments_link(__('Newer comments &rarr;', 'sage')); ?></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

                <?php if (!comments_open() && get_comments_number() != '0' && post_type_supports(get_post_type(), 'comments')) : ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">
                        <?php _e('Comments are closed.', 'sage'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php comment_form(); ?>
            </div><!--End Comments-->
```

The form works correctly, but the comments themselves to display until I add the following:

```
<?php wp_list_comments();?>
```

But then obviously the form and comments appear twice.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't use wp_list_comment ? if i get what you are looking for , is to separate the comment list and the comment form , is that true ?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do - how would I go about that please?

Comment: what if you use **wp_list_comment()** to list the comments , and use **comment_form()** for the form ?

Comment: Tried that, and no comments display until I add this: <?php comments_template(); ?>

Comment: are you in single post or page  ?

Comment: I'm using a Custom Post Type

Comment: Have you tried adding comment support to your custom post type, via **add_post_type_support()**?